# Flutter infinite Scrolling Pagination ListView [Lazy Load]

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, pagination, flutter-layout

**Can anyone add Infinite Scrolling Pagination [Lazy Load]?** so that the app loads 14 products from my server (jsondata) then load another 14 products when i go to the bottom and then load another 14 products so until the end of them [My used code is below]

Any solution or anyone can help me and write it?

```
class ItemsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemsPageState createState() => _ItemsPageState();
}

class _ItemsPageState extends State<ItemsPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<VarientList>> listDrop = [];
  List<ProductBean> productList = [];
  int selected = null;
  dynamic curency;

  List<SubcategoryList> subCatList = [];
  List<Tab> tabs = <Tab>[];
  TabController tabController;

  var value = 0;

  dynamic isFetch = false;
  dynamic isDelete = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getSubCategory();
    super.initState();
  }

  void productListM(catid) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isFetch = true;
      curency = pref.getString('curency');
      productList.clear();
    });
    var vendorId = pref.getInt('vendor_id');
    var client = http.Client();
    var storeProduct = store_subcategoryproduct;
    client.post(storeProduct, body: {
      'vendor_id': '${vendorId}',
      'subcat_id': '${catid}'
    }).then((value) {
      print('${value.body}');
      if (value.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(value.body) as List;
        List<ProductBean> listBean =
            jsonData.map((e) => ProductBean.fromJson(e)).toList();
        if (listBean.length > 0) {
          setState(() {
            productList = List.from(listBean);
          });
        }
      }
      setState(() {
        isFetch = false;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      setState(() {
        isFetch = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
          child: CustomAppBar(
            titleWidget: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'منتجاتي',
                  style: TextStyle(color: kMainTextColor),
                )),
              ],
            ),
                    productListM(subCatList[tabController.index].subcat_id);
                  }),
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              controller: tabController,
              tabs: tabs,
              isScrollable: true,
              labelColor: kMainColor,
              unselectedLabelColor: kLightTextColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 9,
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: tabController,
                    children: tabs.map((tab) {
                      return (productList != null && productList.length > 0)
                          ? ListView.separated(
                              itemCount: productList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                                        context, PageRoutes.editItem,
                                        arguments: {
                                          'selectedItem': productList[index],
                                          'currency': curency
                                        }).then((value) {
                                      productListM(
                                          subCatList[tabController.index]
                                              .subcat_id);
                                    });
                                  },
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no shortage of packages on pub.dev that do this exact thing.

Comment: But i see many of explanations about adding Pagination in flutter but i can only implement it with static local data and  cannot implement it with jsonData

Comment: The tutorials show local data for simplicity's sake, not to show that it's only possible that way. There's no reason you can't replace the local data source with a source that pulls JSON data from a remote source.

Comment: I know but i'm new to flutter so i cannot implement it, the above code is the code of the page which the products load if you can edit and write the lines to make Pagination works with it i will be very happy and thankful.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to implement the pagination myself, I would either use [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) library (`ListView`, `GridView`, `PageView` support) or, if the project is small and I just want it in one place and don't want to add yet another dependency, I would just wrap my `ListView` with `NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>` like below:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
  if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {
    onScrollListener();
  }

  return true;
}

void onScrollListener() {
  if (reachedEnd) {
    return;
  }

  if (!isPageLoading) {
    isPageLoading = true;
    Future.microtask(() async {
      final newItems = await getItemsUseCase.get(page: nextPage);
      if (newItems.length < pageSize) {
        reachedEnd= true;
      } else {
        nextPage++;
      }

      allItems.addAll(newItems);
      isPageLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I've added a complete [code example](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/infinite-scrolling-sliverlist-in-flutter-2236aa050a6c) where I simulate a backend call and load the next page of data on scroll end.